# .Net Core – Binance.Net update view in real time from data model websockets

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, websocket

I have a .Net Core application and I’m using the Binance.Net API. I want to show the trades coming in real time and update my View with the current trades. I’m not sure the correct way to do this. Possibly ajax? The data that is coming in is all c# so that makes it harder where I cant use javascript websockets to update the UI. Unless there is a way around this.
I have a View and also a partialview with a listbox in it. Currently as the websocket data comes in I add it to a model and if I click the button in my partial the listbox shows the recent trades. So I am partially there.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Start Capture");
            //var price = await _marketFeed.StartBTCCapture();

            //var incomingBTC = await _binanceSocketClient.SubscribeToTradeUpdatesAsync("BTCUSD", (data) =>
            //{
            //    //(data);
            //    // _logger.LogInformation(data.Price.ToString());
            //    Console.WriteLine(data.Price);
            //});
            List<TradeResult> trades = new List<TradeResult>();
            await GetPartial(trades);
            //_logger.LogInformation(price.Data);
            //var conn = new WebSocket();

            //HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();
            //httpListener.Prefixes.Add("ws://localhost:50021/StartBTCCapture");
            //httpListener.Start();
            //var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];

            //HttpListenerContext context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();
            //if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
            //{
            //    HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
            //    WebSocket webSocket = webSocketContext.WebSocket;
            //    while (webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            //    {
            //        await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            //    }
            //}

            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> GetPartial(List<TradeResult> trades)
        {


            var incomingBTC = await _binanceSocketClient.SubscribeToTradeUpdatesAsync("BTCUSD", (data) =>
            {
                //(data);
                // _logger.LogInformation(data.Price.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(data.Price);
                trades.Add(new TradeResult
                {
                    Price = data.Price
                });

            });

            return PartialView("BoxView", trades);
        }
//Partial
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach(var obj in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @obj.Price.ToString()
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="btn" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up solving this question.

I ended up adding an IMemoryCache to my .Net Core Web Application.
I then used a PartialView to show the cache on my View.
I used the jquery .load function to show the cache in real time.

```
// PartialView
@model TestVM
<select class="form-control" id="testBox" size="5" style="width:510px;" asp-for="TradeID" 
        asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.Cache ?? string.Empty, "TradeID", "Price"))">
</select>

//Main View
<div id="divadd col-6">
        <partial name="ShowCache.cshtml" />
    </div>
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
function addData(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var element = document.getElementById("lstBox")
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.text = data.s + "\t\t" + data.p + "     " + data.q ;
                opt.value = data;
                element.options.add(opt);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddDataToMemory", "Home")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    //contentType: 'text/plain',
                    data: { model: JSON.stringify(data) },
                    //contentType: "application/json",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    dataType: "json",

                    traditional: true,
                    //data: { model: data },
                    //data: data ,

                   //contentType: type of data your sending
                    //dataType: what you're expecting back from the server: json, html, text, etc
                    //dataType: 'JSON',
                    //'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                })
                    .done(function (e) {
                        @*$.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ShowCache", "Home")',
                            type: 'GET',

                        })*@
                        $('#testBox').load('@Url.Action("ShowCache", "Home")');
                        //alert('done');
                    })
                return false;
            }
        }
}
//Controller
        public IActionResult ShowCache()
        {
            if (_memoryCache.TryGetValue<List<string>>("Data", out List<string> cache))
            {
                List<TestVM> lstTest = new List<TestVM>();
                foreach (string model in cache)
                {
                   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model))
                   {
                        var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(model);
                        var price = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("p");
                        var id = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("t");
                        var symbol = jsonDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("s");


                        TestVM testVM = new TestVM
                        {
                            Price = Convert.ToDecimal(price.ToString()),
                            TradeID = Convert.ToInt64(id.ToString()),
                            Symbol = symbol.ToString()
                        };
                        lstTest.Add(testVM);
                   }
                }
                //ViewBag.Cache = cache;
                ViewBag.Cache = lstTest;

            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```